# What is an example of a matrix with eigenvalues $-1\pm i$

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I need an example of a non-diagonal, real entried matrix with eigenvalues $-1\pm i$. Does anyone know how to construct such an example?

Comment: Start from the diagonalized matrix and "dediagonalize" it with $PDP^{-1}$ for some invertible $P$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: compute the eigenvalues of
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
a & b \\
-b & a
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Answer (score 2):

For example a $\;2\times2\;$ matrix with characteristic polynomial $\;x^2+2x+2\;$:

$$A=\begin{pmatrix}\;0&\;1\\-2&-2\end{pmatrix}$$

How? First, construct the polynomial $\;(x-(-1+i))(x-(-1-i))=x^2+2x+2\;$ (check this), then use the [companion matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Companion_matrix) for this polynomial.

Answer (score 2):

Due to the bijective correspondence between transformations $z\rightarrow az$ and plane similitudes (see for example http://www.cut-the-knot.org/arithmetic/algebra/ComplexNumbersGeometry.shtml), $a=-1\pm i=\sqrt{2}e^{\pm 3i\pi/4}$ is naturally associated with the similitude matrix:

$$S=\sqrt{2}\begin{bmatrix}\cos \theta & -\sin \theta\\ \sin \theta & \cos \theta\end{bmatrix} \  \ \text{with} \ \ \ \theta=3\pi/4$$

(a rotation followed by an homothety); thus it suffices to take:

$$S=\begin{bmatrix}-1 & -1\\1 & -1\end{bmatrix} $$

Answer (score 1):

You set $ Q=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$ it is an invertible matrix. You set $A=Q\begin{pmatrix} -1+i & 0 \\ 0 & -1-i \end{pmatrix}Q^{-1}=\begin{pmatrix} -1+i & 0 \\ 2i & -1-i \end{pmatrix}$.
$A$ has the eigen values needed and is not diagonal.

Comment: But  the OP is asking for a real valued matrix.